# How should I level my tiles on a concrete slab with 1/2in tilt

Tags: tile

I am tiling on a concrete slab which is flat but tilted, and I have just less than 1/2in to fill, at the lowest point.

To compensate for the tilt, should I

- apply adhesive cement on both tile & surface, with a 1/2in notched trowel, or
- fill & level with cement first?

Tiles are 1' x 2'. The affected area is about 50 sqft (about 25 tiles)

The picture shows my levelling lumber along the top of the tile surface, a loose piece of tile, and the gap, with a 1/2 notched trowel for reference.

[image]

Comment: Are you using backer board on top of concrete?

Comment: @EdBeal, no but that's maybe an idea to fill. What were your thoughts?

Comment: I would use a mortar bed to fill was the tilt for drainage? That would be by only concern , I was using my phone and the resolution’s not the best with the shadows but a bed of mortar will stick well to the existing slab make sure to wet it down first, sometimes if the concrete is really slick I will acid etch with muriatic acid  or pressure wash to provide a better surface then lay a layer of mortar let it set and continue tiling.

Comment: Awesome @EdBeal. The concrete is rough. There was no drainage. But now I'm curious: what would the backer board have accomplished?

Comment: I thought you were using backer board and that would have been my question to you. We bought a bank repo that the owner thought he knew how to do tile, yup you guessed it tile on backer, the first freeze it started buckling was great for us got the place for 10 cents on the dollar. It looked like land mines had gone off everywhere.

Comment: @EdBeal - tile on backer over concrete? That's funny ... :P

Comment: I had never seen backer buckle like that it was only stuck to the concrete at the joints both the front walk and back patio a full trailer load of tile and backer board. Never happier for having purchased the power dump trailer. The crazy thing both areas the concrete was in good shape we could not etch the joints discoloration so we acid colored them and it looked great. All the inside tile was ok at least screwed down.